# TikZ / PGF : why use \addplot instead of \plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I cannot understand the difference between addplot and a simple draw plot. Can someone explain why it is generally preferred on forums to do the second thing on this MWE ?

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\starttext
\starttikzpicture
  \draw plot[domain=0:3.1415] (\x,{sin(180*\x/3.1415)});
\stoptikzpicture

\hairline

\starttikzpicture
  \startaxis[axis x line=none, axis y line=none]
    \addplot[domain=0:180] {sin(x)};
  \stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

Comment: The second one only works inside of an `axis` environment. Not sure if this is just me, but the second one has an easier syntax since it's built for that environment. However if the majority of the image is in regular `tikz`, I'll switch to the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons for using `pgfplots` rather than `tikz`, here are some that I could think of right now:

- Automatic scaling: `pgfplots` will scale things so that the plot doesn't become very large. Try plotting `exp(x)` for example, instead of `sin(x)`.
- Automatic ticklabels and axis lines. This doesn't apply for your example of course, but often you want to have axis lines and ticks.
- Easy plotting of datafiles. E.g. if you have a text file `data.txt` that looks like

  ```
  time value
  0 0
  1 2
  2 10
  ```

  you can do `\addplot table[x=time,y=value] {data.txt};`

On the other hand some of these may be reasons for not using `pgfplots`. If you're making some qualitative plot with a lot of annotations, then it might in some cases be easier to use pure TikZ, as that makes things like `\foreach` easier.